# Meaning of the phrase “not this little black duck”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does the phrase “not this little black duck” mean? I know it’s common among Australian people but I am not sure what does it mean.

Comment: https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-duc1.htm

Comment: Is it common among other anglophone countries?

Comment: Never heard it in the US. Are all the ducks in Oz black, too?

Comment: I've never heard it in the UK.

Comment: @KillingTime You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: Daffy refers to himself as "the little black duck" in [this brief YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9obAJnKbfw).

Comment: [correction: but I am not sure what it means]

Answer (score 3):

It's a direct reference to the Looney Tunes cartoon Daffy duck. In multiple episodes, when confronted with a difficult situation he walked away stating "not this little black duck". As in:

> Your not telling me what to do/I'm not walking into that situation.

For example: What a confirmed bachelor might say being set up on a blind date with a woman who is 6 months pregnant.

Comment: Confirming it is a direct reference to Daffy Duck, and caught on in Australia since it was a very typical thing to say down here. For those looking for deeper meaning, sorry to say there was no resonance with black Australians, ethnic underdogs, rallying cries etc. - it was a simple, funny thing that we kids picked up from watching TV.

Answer (score 1):

As an Australian I can say I’ve never heard the expression.  However, it does seem to be valid and is explained in World Wide Words on:

https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-duc1.htm

In brief, according to this source, it is used as an indication that the speaker is not so stupid as they are being taken to be.

**Following a comment from Stuart F (thank you), I quote the source of the link which said, in part:**

"The consensus is that it does come from the Warner Bros Daffy Duck cartoons, Daffy, of course, being a small black duck who used it as his catchphrase. Quite why Australians took this particular character to their hearts is a topic for some sociologist in need of a thesis.      . . .

[Apparently] Daffy’s catchphrase is indeed said to have appealed first to black Australians. Presumably they were able to identify with this black underdog character, or at least find a rallying cry in his catchphrase as an indicator of ethnic pride. But how it shifted into the wider Australian community is still far from clear."

Comment: This answer, which provides a good reference, really needs to be combined with the other answer which explains that it comes from Daffy Duck. Please include information in your post rather than just providing a link, just in case World Wide Words ever disappears.